# Equivalent for drop table table_name cascade constraints in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-drop

My question is that in Oracle we can use `drop table table_name cascade constraints` to drop a referenced table object. How can I achieve the same in SQL Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I know there is not one command in MsSql, but you can use INFORMATION_SCHEMA and dynamic SQL.

Something like this:

```
DECLARE @database nvarchar(50)
DECLARE @table nvarchar(50)

set @database = 'MyDatabase'
set @table = 'MyTable'

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(255)
WHILE EXISTS(select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS where constraint_catalog = @database and table_name = @table)
BEGIN
    select    @sql = 'ALTER TABLE ' + @table + ' DROP CONSTRAINT ' + CONSTRAINT_NAME 
    from    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS 
    where    constraint_catalog = @database and 
            table_name = @table
    exec    sp_executesql @sql
END
```

Comment: thank you demas for the answer, but i wished if there could be a single line of tool for that. If any clues you find pls suggest me.

Comment: You can create stored procedure from this code and use it as single line tool :)

Comment: Of course demas, your suggestion is nice. If we really do not have any single line SYNTAX from MSSQL, i conclude we've no option rather than what you suggested. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option to let Management Studio generate a script that alters/drops all constraints on dependent objects.

I found the desciption here [SQL Server drop table cascade equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4858488/sql-server-drop-table-cascade-equivalent/5488670#5488670)