# How to delete rows in associated SQL tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, database-design, stored-procedures

I want to delete rows in GlassesColor table that associated with GlassesID in Glasses table.
I want to implement this in stored procedure.The stored procedure gets only one parameter from client side , a CollectionID.

Here are the following tables:

[image]

Here is example of tables content:

[image]

Any idea how can i implement this?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: +1 to everyone!!! We all agree that it should be ON DELETE CASCADE on the foreign key constraint!  :-) :-) :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Manually deleting would be something like this:

```
delete 
from GlassesColor 
where GlassesID in (select GlassesID from Glasses where CollectionID = 3)
```

However, unless this is a one time cleanup, you should start specifying foreign key cascading rules, like the other answers already suggested.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to define FOREIGN KEYS with CASCADE options for DELETE.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933119%28v=sql.80%29.aspx

I see you already have Foreign Keys defined, so you just need to make sure they have CASCADE option for DELETE.

Answer (score 2):

Without stored procedure, use Constrains -> http://www.mssqlcity.com/Articles/General/using_constraints.htm OnDelete Cascade, so when you delete row in Glasses, it will deleted in Glasses color also.

Answer (score 2):

In your foreign key constraint for the `GlassesColor` join table, have `on delete cascade`.  What that means is when the primary key referenced record is deleted, the corresponding foreign key reference row will also be deleted.

So your `GlassesColor` table definition would look like this:

```
create table GlassesColor
(
    GlassesId int foreign key references Glasses(GlassesID) on delete cascade,
    .....
)
go
```

Answer (score 2):

I answered something similar for using the INFORMATION_SCHEMA in MSSQL

[SQL Server: drop table cascade equivalent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4858488/sql-server-drop-table-cascade-equivalent/)

Answer (score 2):

Here's the easiest way to do it in Microsoft SQL Server:  when you create the foreign key constraint, add `ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE` to its definition.  I'm assuming you want changes to GlassesID to also propogate.  ;-)   If not, then you don't need the "ON UPDATE CASCADE".

Example:

```
ALTER TABLE
  [GlassesColor]
WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT
  [FK_GlassesColor_GlassesID]
FOREIGN KEY
  ([glassesID]) REFERENCES [Glasses] ([glassesID])
ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
```