# Drop All constraints in a Table

Tags: sql-server-2008, constraints

Am trying to write script for removing Constraints.

I have the below function to select the Constarints in my DataBase

```
SELECT  name
    FROM sys.foreign_keys
```

And I have written alter scripts using the above scripts

```
SELECT 
    'ALTER TABLE ' + OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id) + 
    ' DROP CONSTRAINT ' + name
FROM sys.foreign_keys
```

Using the above query how can I execute these constraints ?

I can use `DROP DATABASE DBName`. But am just trying to drop tables by dropping Constraints.

is it possible without going for SP ? Or any easy ways I can proceed?

Comment: Check the comment in this [article][1] .


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6130023/2232256

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Well you can always copy the output from the bottom pane, paste it into the top pane, and hit F5. Or you can build a string to execute directly:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

SELECT @sql += N'
ALTER TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(parent_object_id))
    + '.' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id)) + 
    ' DROP CONSTRAINT ' + QUOTENAME(name) + ';'
FROM sys.foreign_keys;

PRINT @sql;
-- EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

(When you are happy with the `PRINT` output, comment it out and uncomment the `EXEC`. Note that the print output will be truncated to 8K in Management Studio but the variable really holds the entire command.)

Also I don't know how this really relates to whether you are using a stored procedure or not, or why you are trying to do it "w/o going for SP"... this query can be run as a stored procedure or not, it all depends on how often you're going to call it, where the procedure lives, etc.

Comment: Thanks @Aaron. that is Exactly what i was looking for. Ya i ll convert to SP as you said

Comment: Yes it is essentially string concatenation over every row in the result. You could also say `SELECT @sql = @sql + N'...` in fact that is how you had to do it in SQL Server 2005. This is newer syntax introduced in SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 32):

This worked for me in SQL Server 2008:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

SELECT @SQL += N'
ALTER TABLE ' + OBJECT_NAME(PARENT_OBJECT_ID) + ' DROP CONSTRAINT ' + OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) + ';' 
FROM SYS.OBJECTS
WHERE TYPE_DESC LIKE '%CONSTRAINT' AND OBJECT_NAME(PARENT_OBJECT_ID) = 'YOUR_TABLE';

PRINT @SQL
--EXECUTE(@SQL)
```

Of course, uncomment the `EXECUTE(@SQL)` when ready to run

Comment: I prefer this one because it shows you how to target specific tables if that's your goal.

Comment: There is one mistake in this statement. If constraint name will have dots in its name then execution will fail. You must wrap constraint name in square brackets:

`DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';

SELECT @SQL += N'
ALTER TABLE ' + OBJECT_NAME(PARENT_OBJECT_ID) + ' DROP CONSTRAINT [' + OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) + '];' 
FROM SYS.OBJECTS
WHERE TYPE_DESC LIKE '%CONSTRAINT' AND OBJECT_NAME(PARENT_OBJECT_ID) = 'YOUR_TABLE';

--PRINT (@SQL)
EXECUTE(@SQL)`

Also if you don't want to drop primary key then add one more condition to the WHERE clause: `AND [type] != 'PK'`

Comment: Thanks @ViktorsTelle. I had an issue since my constraint contains dots. Solved by  your answer.

Answer (score 6):

The correct-marked question does not work for me. But this works for me in SQL Server 2017:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

SELECT @sql += N'
ALTER TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(parent_object_id))
    + '.' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id)) +
    ' DROP CONSTRAINT ' + QUOTENAME(name) + ';'
FROM sys.objects
WHERE type_desc LIKE '%CONSTRAINT'
    AND OBJECT_NAME(PARENT_OBJECT_ID) LIKE 'your_table_name';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: While this code-only post might answer the question, please add an explanation of why it does so. This will help future readers evaluate the answer for their situation.

Comment: @TomBrunberg Any reason you didn't make the same comment on the other two code-only answers? Are you specifically asking Alexandre for why this fixes what issue he had with the accepted answer? That might be an important distinction for him to keep in mind for why you'd like him to improve this answer.