# Drop all constraints

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a simple script, which display all constraints of some table:

```
SELECT *
FROM DB_NAME.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_TABLE_USAGE
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' AND TABLE_NAME = 'TestTable'
```

How I can drop all constraints in `TestTable` and use selection of previous query (MS SQL Server 2012)? Or it will be bad way to drop constraints?

I found some solutions, but I don't understand where they get information about constraints.

Comment: Possible dublicate of [Drop All constraints in a Table](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15785405/4275342)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to build a string with script like:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

SELECT @sql += N'
ALTER TABLE ' + TABLE_NAME +
    ' DROP CONSTRAINT ' + CONSTRAINT_NAME + ';'
DB_NAME.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_TABLE_USAGE
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' AND TABLE_NAME = 'TestTable';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: I prefer this one over the other option linked here because Occam's razor.