# What do "near "CASCADE"" and "near "CONSTRAINTS" error mean in MySQL?

Tags: sql, mysql, phpmyadmin, syntax-error

I apologise for the incorrect use of sql terms, I'm still a novice. So, I produced a ddl script from a relational model, converted it to MySQL and tried to "run" (the app Im' running it at is called phpMyAdmin)  it but whatever I did was met with failure as these error kept occuring:

Unrecognized keyword. (near "CASCADE" at position 203)
Unexpected presumption. (near "CONSTRAINTS" at position 211)

If anybody has a word of advice I'd gladly accept it.
I'll provide the actual line of code that the error occures (which is the first line of the script too):

`DROP TABLE ad CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;`

The script is for a database. I tried to "reverse enngineer" it in the entity model and priduce a different script but the same error kept occuring.

Comment: Unexpected keyword `CONSTRAINTS`.

Comment: `DROP [TEMPORARY] TABLE [IF EXISTS] tbl_name [, tbl_name] ... [RESTRICT | CASCADE]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Brad Troll Error means keywords " Cascade" and "Constraint" are unrecognized as they are used to delete all rows from the child table once all tables from the parent table are deleted.

Try using the code :

**DROP TABLE ad;**

It will run and will not give you any error.

Answer (score 0):

[From the MySQL docs](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/drop-table/) we can see that your command syntax is illegal.


In fact in MySQL you can't delete on cascade like you want to do it :

> `RESTRICT` and `CASCADE` are allowed to make porting from other database systems easier. In MariaDB, they do nothing.

Hope it help you.

Comment: Thank you kindly! Do you have any suggestion for what to do next, or how to "fix" it? I realize it probably is very elementary, but I would appreciate it. Either way, thank you for answering my question!

Comment: With pleasure, maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4858488/sql-server-drop-table-cascade-equivalent) can help you