# Insert Statement to insert Data from one table to another

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-insert

I have the following SQL Code to Insert Data From One table to Another by comparing the Data in two table. The PK in the destination table are `[bomItem], [bomRev], [bomEntry]`.

I want to Insert if `ItemID in source table = bomItem field in Dest. table` **AND** `[rev](field in Source tbl)NOT=[bomRev](in destination tbl)`.

When I tried to run the script i get the following error

> Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 46
>   The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_MIBOMD_MIBOMH". The conflict occurred in database "MITESTCO", table "dbo.MIBOMH".
>   The statement has been terminated.

```
    USE [MITESTCO];
    GO

   INSERT INTO [MIBOMD] 
    ([bomItem], [bomRev], [bomEntry], [partId], [qty],[lead])
 SELECT [ItemID], [rev], [bomEntry], [partid], [qty],[lead]
 FROM [assy] 
 WHERE  [rev] IN (SELECT [bomRev] FROM [MIBOMH])
        AND [ItemID] IN (SELECT [bomItem] FROM [MIBOMH])
        AND [ItemID] IN (SELECT [ItemID] FROM [MIITEM])
        AND [partid] IN (SELECT [ItemID] FROM [MIITEM]);
```

Comment: Error has nothing directly to do with query but design structure of your database tables. As error says a foreign key constraint is being violated which by its name may involve the appending table, `dbo.MIBOMD` with `dbo.MIBOMH`. Maybe you have one-to-many table relationship between these two (parent/child) and are appending records in child, leaving connecting parent ID NULL.

Comment: @Parfait Thanks! Yes i have one-to-Many relationship and i have the same data/record in the parent and Child the only d/c is the `rev` field. The Primary Keys in the parent tables are `bomRev` and `bomItem`. How can i resolve this you said Apeending But i dont know how that work Can you explain me more?

Comment: Check your constraints: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499332/how-to-check-if-a-constraint-exists-in-sql-server

Comment: You could look into turning off the constraints temporarily, do your inserts and turn it back on.

Comment: @freakyhat Thanks How can i add it back the constraints?

Comment: I've posted what you require as an answer. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

To disable all constraints in the database -

```
EXEC sp_msforeachtable "ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT all"

-- Insert data
```

To switch them back on -

```
exec sp_msforeachtable @command1="print '?'", @command2="ALTER TABLE ? WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT all"
```