# Altering a sqlserver table column to add a 'Not NULL' constraint

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, constraints, alter-table, notnull

I want to add a constraint of not null into an existing column in a table.  After doing some operation of merging data. I want to alter the table to add the constraint not null. However, I do want to first verify the existance of the NotNULL constraint otherwise on the subsequesnt of running the script. The file will throw error.  So what should be the way.

I want to try something like:

```
IF NOT EXISTs (Select..   )

BEGIN

ALTER table ....

END
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499332/how-to-check-if-a-constraint-exists-in-sql-server

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I do not understand this correctly, but there's no need to check for *existance*. You can alter a table's column to `NOT NULL` over and over again - if you like.

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE Test(ID INT,SomeValue VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO Test VALUES(1,NULL),(2,'Value 2'),(NULL,'Value NULL');
```

--Ups, ID should not be NULL, but this throws an error

```
--ALTER TABLE Test ALTER COLUMN ID INT NOT NULL;
```

--First have to correct the missing value

```
UPDATE Test SET ID=3 WHERE SomeValue='Value NULL';
```

--Now this works

```
ALTER TABLE Test ALTER COLUMN ID INT NOT NULL;
```

--No problem to put this statement again. No need to check for existance...

```
ALTER TABLE Test ALTER COLUMN ID INT NOT NULL;
```

--Clean-Up

```
GO
DROP TABLE Test;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use views in `sys` namespace for this purpose. Something like this.

```
select c.name,t.name,c.is_nullable 
from sys.all_columns c
inner join sys.tables t on c.object_id=t.object_id
where t.name = 'MyTable' and c.name = 'myCol';
```

and then `alter table ... alter column...`