# How to check if constraint exists before dropping it with knex.js

Tags: javascript, knex.js

So I want to drop a constraint using Knex.js, but I need to check if the constraint is present before I do this.  I haven't found a way yet.   Anyone have an idea?

Here's my function:

```
async alterTable_dropConstraint(tableName, constraintDropped) {
    return await knex.schema.raw(`ALTER TABLE ${tableName} DROP CONSTRAINT ${constraintDropped}`);
}
```

---

Answer (or the code that worked for me):
Add 'IF EXISTS'

```
async alterTable_dropConstraint(tableName, constraintDropped) {
    return await knex.schema.raw(`ALTER TABLE ${tableName} DROP CONSTRAINT IF EXISTS ${constraintDropped}`);
}
```

Comment: Is this helps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499332/how-to-check-if-a-constraint-exists-in-sql-server

Comment: After reading that link, I tried adding:  a chec: knex.schema.raw(`SELECT 1 FROM ${tableName} WHERE CONSTRAINT_TYPE='UNIQUE' AND CONSTRAINT  = ${constraintDropped}`) - but that didn't help.  It finds it when it is not available.