# How to check whether a default constraint with no name exist on a column

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with a default constraint defined as below.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test](
    [LicenseKey] [int] NULL,
    [CreatedOnDate] [datetime] NOT NULL DEFAULT (getdate())
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

How to check whether this constraint exist before I run a separate script (like `ALTER TABLE ADD CONSTRAINT`) to add the constraint?

I referred following post
[How to check if a Constraint exists in Sql server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499332/how-to-check-if-a-constraint-exists-in-sql-server)
But that post handles only names default constraints check.

Comment: The link should have given you a clue - there is a table for default constraints aptly named [sys.default_constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-default-constraints-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16). I'll point out that the CreatedOnDate probably should not allow nulls either.

Comment: @SMor I already tried with the scripts mentioned there... It does not list this constraint

Comment: It has to be there.  Every constraint MUST have a name.  If you don't provide one then SQL Server will generate one for you automatically and it will be listed in `sys.default_constraints`.  Why don't you just give it a name so you don't have to go through this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A column can only have one default constraint on it.

You can find the details for any such default constraint with the below query against [`sys.default_constraints`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-default-constraints-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

```
DECLARE @TableName NVARCHAR(500) = N'dbo.Test', 
        @ColumnName sysname = N'CreatedOnDate';

SELECT d.definition,
       d.is_system_named, /* 1 if no name given by the user and was allocated a system generated one */
       d.name
FROM   sys.default_constraints AS d
       INNER JOIN sys.columns AS c
               ON d.parent_object_id = c.object_id
                  AND d.parent_column_id = c.column_id
WHERE  d.parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID(@TableName, N'U')
       AND c.name = @ColumnName;
```

NB: If you later need to re-create the default constraint (perhaps to reference `SYSUTCDATETIME` instead of `GETDATE`) the constraint name created by your current `CREATE TABLE` will be different in all environments and you will have to resort to dynamic SQL to do this. It is advisable to always name your constraints (for permanent tables).