# Get the name of a columns default constraint on SQL Server 2000?

Tags: sql-server-2000, constraints

How do I get the name of a columns default contraint on a SQL Server 2000 installation? As far as I know sys.default_constraints is not available. Its different on every DB, the structure is like DF_table_column__3DE8FB0E for example.

Thanks :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I find a default constraint using INFORMATION_SCHEMA?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141682/how-do-i-find-a-default-constraint-using-information-schema)

Comment: Now the question is, after knowing the name in some variable, how do I drop that contraint? *alter table table drop constraint @ConstraintName* is not working ...

Comment: That's the correct syntax. Can you elaborate on "not working?" Is there an error message?

Comment: You can't parameterise it. You need dynamic SQL.

Comment: Wrong syntax near '@ContraintName'. Dynamic SQL?

Comment: Ah. Didn't realize you were literally using a `@ConstraintName` variable. Martin Smith's comment is correct.

Comment: Fount it: 

    exec('alter table table drop constraint ' + @ConstraintName)

Comment: @grady - You would put the string `'ALTER TABLE T DROP CONSTRAINT ' + QUOTENAME(@ConstraintName)` into a variable `@dynsql` then `EXEC(@dynsql)`

Answer (score 0):

Try using INFORMATION_SCHEMA, SQL Server's implementation of the SQL 92 self-describing features.

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE
```

Comment: This only gives me those columns for a certain table that are a foreign key.