# Stored procedure with parameter that defaults to default constraint value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, default-constraint

I have a `Users` table that has an `ImgPath` column. I want that `ImgPath` column to be not null and default to a specific path. In the table declaration, I have this:

```
[ImgPath] VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL 
    CONSTRAINT [DF_Users_ImgPath] DEFAULT ('/images/default.jpg')
```

I have a `SaveUser` stored procedure that is a merge statement to either update the user with the new `ImgPath` or to create a new user with the associated `ImgPath`.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SaveUser] 
    (@UserId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, 
     @ImgPath VARCHAR(256)) 
AS
    MERGE [dbo].[Users] AS TARGET
    USING (SELECT @UserId, @ImgPath) AS SOURCE ([UserId], [ImgPath]) ON (TARGET.[UserId] = SOURCE.[UserId])

    WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE 
            SET TARGET.[ImgPath] = SOURCE.[ImgPath]

    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
        INSERT ([UserId], [ImgPath])
        VALUES (SOURCE.[UserId], SOURCE.[ImgPath]);
```

How can I edit the stored procedure so that if ImgPath is null, it defaults to the DEFAULT CONSTRAINT value without having the value in both the table declaration and stored procedure?

If I send NULL or set the default value of `@ImgPath` to NULL, this does not work since NULL overrides the default value and since the column is not nullable, it throws an error.

`COALESCE` and `ISNULL` do not like `DEFAULT` being a fallback parameter.

I would also like to not have some nasty if/case statement that executes two `MERGE` statements.

Comment: A brute force solution would be to get the actual default value from the system information schemas. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141682/how-do-i-find-a-default-constraint-using-information-schema) question will lead you in that terrible direction. (`sys.default_constraints.definition` contains the value parenthetically.) _(I'd rather be diving.)_

Answer (score 0):

Not as farmillar with MERGE as I should be, but this may work.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SaveUser] 
    (@UserId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, 
     @ImgPath VARCHAR(256)) 
AS
    MERGE [dbo].[Users] AS TARGET
    USING (SELECT @UserId, @ImgPath) AS SOURCE ([UserId], [ImgPath]) ON (TARGET.[UserId] = SOURCE.[UserId])

    WHEN MATCHED AND SOURCE.[ImgPath] is not null THEN
        UPDATE 
            SET TARGET.[ImgPath] = SOURCE.[ImgPath]


    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET AND SOURCE.[ImgPath] is not null THEN
        INSERT ([UserId], [ImgPath])
        VALUES (SOURCE.[UserId], SOURCE.[ImgPath])
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET AND SOURCE.[ImgPath] IS NULL then
        INSERT ([UserId])
        VALUES (SOURCE.[UserId]);
```

This *should* only fiddle with ImgPath when ImgPath has a value.

Comment: This answer just removed the second WHEN MATCHED but doesn't account for when the user already exists and NULL is coming in for ImgPath.